# load 100% data using services while displaying splash screen

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I have an Android App, which shows a "Splash Screen" for 3 seconds. After that, the MainActivity gets loaded.

Unfortunately the MainActivity takes additional ~4 seconds to load. On first startup even longer. However when the App is loaded, everything runs smooth.

I am using Async-Task for this, but desired result is not obtained and sometimes app crashes. Can someone help me please?

**SplashScreen.java**

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    new Fetchdata().execute();
```

}

private class Fetchdata extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,FetchApiService.class);
        startService(intent);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.interrupted();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){

        Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Some heavy processing
    //starting services
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,FetchApiService.class);
        startService(intent);

}
```

}

Comment: Since everyone hates splash screens and they're worthless, I suggest changing it to a loading screen that shows the loading progress. Then you make your service which downloads the data.  The loading screen then binds to the downloading Service.

Comment: If you want help with your error, it's important to actually post what is the error you are getting. Don't ask the community to do static analysis to find your bug.